# Visualise audio waveform from video local file using Qmedia player

Tags: c++, qt

I try without success to plot waveform using `qMediaPlayer` and `QaudioProbe` object to get the `QAudioBuffer` but it's always fails when I try:

```
player =  new QMediaPlayer;
audio  =  new QAudioProbe ;
QAudioRecorder *recorder = new QAudioRecorder();


if (audio->setSource(player))
{
    // Probing succeeded, audioProbe->isValid() should be true.
    std::cout << "probing succed"<< std::endl;
    connect(audio, SIGNAL(audioBufferProbed(QAudioBuffer)), this,
                  SLOT(processBuffer(QAudioBuffer)));
}
```

this line:

```
if (audio->setSource(player))
```

always return false!

when I replace QMediaPlayer by QAudioRecorder the setSource function works well.

do you have any idea to do that, or m'I in a wrong direction?
otherwise is there other way to split audio from video file.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on QMediaPlayer, I would gather that since the property audioAvailable can change, the default is that audioAvailable is false.
If there is no audio available, the documentation of setSource states that

> "If the media object does not support monitoring audio, this function
>   will return false."

Try loading an actual piece of media, that has audio available (check that first) before trying to set the source

Comment: Problem almost solved: in fact, the documentation example Player doesn't plot the waveform when it is built using qt 5.2.1 mingw 4.8, but when I change the kit to qt 5.3 MSVC2010 and nothing else it works well. I tried also with  qt 5.3 mingw 4.8 but it doesn't work. very strange!! maybe a bug!!